# Rosbag on srvs?

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Is it possible to record the requests and responses over a srv with rosbag? When I use rosbag record on the srv name, the bag files are empty. I can't find any documentation about using rosbag with srvs so I thought I should ask here to confirm.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219126/rosbag-on-srvs?/) by [sterlingm](https://answers.ros.org/users/2199/sterlingm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 380 on 2015-10-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosbag cannot be used to record service calls. See this [ticket](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/250) for the reasoning.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2015-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2